# How can nontrivial elementary embeddings of the universe to some inner model be surjective?

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Consider $\kappa$ to the least measurable cardinal, or equivalently $\kappa$ is the critical point for an elementary embedding $j:V \rightarrow M$ from the universe $V$ to an inner model $M$ (critical point means $\kappa$ is the least ordinal such that $\kappa<j(\kappa)$; Note $j$ must take ordinals to ordinals and for all ordinals $\alpha\leq j(\alpha)$).

It is common knowledge (reference: Set Theory, by Jech pg. 289) that $j(V)=M$, i.e. $j$ is surjective. I must be misunderstanding something because I don't see how this can be possible when there are gaps between ordinals in $j(V)$?: If $\beta$ is an ordinal such that $\kappa<j(\beta)<j(\kappa)$ (for instance $j(\beta)=\kappa+1$) then $j(\beta)<j(\kappa)$ implies $\beta<\kappa$ hence $j(\beta)=\beta<\kappa$, which contradicts $\kappa<j(\beta)$.

Thanks.

Comment: $j$ is *not* surjective. What is true is that $\bigcup j[V]=M$.

Comment: Note that in your reference, Jech is talking about _classes_. The notational convention $j(X)$ means $\{x\in M : X(x)\}$, when thinking of $X$ as a formula. Hence $j(V) = \{x\in M : x=x\} = M$.

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification!

Comment: To pile on the previous comments, this is the difference between $j{"}V=\{j(x)\mid x\in V\}$ which is of course a proper subclass of $M$ and $j(V)$ which is the reinterpretation of $V$ in $M$, which is $M$.